# Why is an 80MHz PIC32 using an 8MHz AND a 32,768Hz crystal?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, frequency, crystal

I saw [this](https://www.olimex.com/Products/PIC/Proto/PIC-32MX/resources/PIC-P32MX-sch.gif) schematic, and they are using a PIC32 microprocessor that can do 80MHz, but they are using an 8MHz crystal on OSC1 and OSC2. Are they running the processor at 8MHz or is there some sort of multiplier or something. And what does the other 32,768Hz crystal on SOSCI and SOSCO do.

Comment: Fig 8-1 , page 93 http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/61143H.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many modern microcontrollers come with internal PLL's. PLL stands for phase locked loop, and one of the applications is frequency multiplier.

Some (but not all) microcontrollers allow reconfiguration of the PLL multiplier/divider settings, which allows you to set an arbitrary frequency.

Some chips also feature a separate USB or audio I2S PLL allowing the CPU to run at a different/faster frequency than 48MHz which is obligatory for the USB peripheral.

I recommended looking up the oscillator or clock chapter of a microcontroller, for PIC32MX795 that is chapter 8 of the datasheet. This is very detailed in how exactly you can set up the CPU clock, PLL source and some constraints (e.g. PLL input clock must be 4 to 5MHz after input division).

The secondary oscillator is also shown in that block diagram. 32.768kHz is often used for RTC (32768 ticks through a 15-bit counter is 1Hz output). It's a low-power clock that can be left running in deep-sleep modes. Given the tight tolerances for time-keeping (especially if time synchronization is absent for long periods), you need an external crystal oscillator.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to tell from the schematic alone what frequency the main clock is running at; it is possible to control any multiplier or scaler via fuses and/or software. As for the other crystal, it's for low-frequency timing such as a RTC.